# Value comparison with NSString - Xcode

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, string-comparison

I'm trying to compare a value to one stored in a NSString, but I get the following error:

> Implicit conversion of int to 'NSArray *' is disallowed with ARC

Here is my code:

```
NSString *tmplabel = [tmpC description];

temp.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat: @"%.f", [tmplabel doubleValue]];


if (tmpC >= 10) {

    // perform action

}

else {

    // perform action
}
```

How can I do this comparison? I just want to see if the value stored is bigger than or equal to 10.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @vcsjones tmpC is a floating point value which is retrieved from a JSON feed.

Comment: what line of the code up there is the "`implicit conversion`" error being thrown on?  what is "`temp`"?  Is it a UILabel or?

Comment: Since tmpC is coming from JSON there is a good chance it is converted as an NSString. Trying doing `if ([tmpC floatValue] >= 10.0) {` this is just an assumption though since we cannot see much code.